# Boundary of stable maps and transversality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Fulton and pandharipande in [FP-notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9608011.pdf) prove that if we consider $Def_G(\mu)$ as deformation of a map $\mu:C \to X$ from nodal curve with $q$ nodes and with preserving dual graph then we have $dimDef_G(\mu)=dim \overline{M}_{0,n}(X,\beta,\bar{t})-q $

then they say that $\mu$ lie in intersection of $q$ branches of the boundary and because of above calculation branches intersect transversally at $\mu$.

my question is about last paragraph:what does mean here by branches of the boundary and why dimension calculation indicate transversality?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  I recommend that you find an expert in your department with whom you can discuss such questions in a one-on-one session.  To answer one part of your question, the dimension inequality is also valid for the Zariski tangent space, and this is what implies transversality.

Comment: yes you are right i should find someone but why $\mu$ lies in intersection of $q$ branches of boundry?